# Oracle - Invalid Identifier for column name

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran into an interesting situation with a `NUMBER` field.

Here is a simplified example.

When I select a particular field have happens to be 29 characters long, it works just fine.

```
select FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX
from table;
```

In the report where this query is being used, the query does not return headers (this is an eText type XML publisher report).  But when I run the query with a `UNION`, selecting the header names, I get an invalid identifier error.

```
SELECT "FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX" FROM dual
UNION
SELECT FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX FROM table1;
```

Returns:

```
ORA-00904: "LINE_RECEIPT_AMNT_AT_COST_USD": invalid identifier
```

The max length of a field name in Oracle DB is 30 chars.  Am I hitting this limitation?  I think not as this, for example:

```
SELECT "FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XXxxxxx" FROM dual;
```

..gives:

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

What is wrong with the `UNION`?

Single quotes do not work either.  This is a `NUMBER` field.

```
SELECT 'FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX FROM table1;
```

..gives:

```
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

Comment: What if you drop the double quotes?  Maybe Oracle is somehow counting them.

Comment: `SELECT "FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX" FROM dual` probably doesn't work since dual doesn't have that field.

Comment: It gives the same error, with or without the quotes.

Comment: @Adder - ```dual``` doesnt work in that way.

Comment: `dual` works that way. It gives the error `invalid identifier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Standin answer lead me to solution.

Because the selected field is a number, just need to cast is as a char - along with the single quotes.

```
SELECT 'FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT to_char(FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX) FROM table1;
```

Comment: The SQL error reported in the question is because the double quotes are used to surround identifiers, not string literals. Oracle is looking for a column of that name in table `DUAL`, and that column name does not exist in DUAL. Changing those to single quotes now makes it a string literal, and fixes that problem. (We would see  that with just running the first SELECT, without the UNION.)  Secondarily, we are running into a restriction on UNION set operation, number of columns has to match exactly, and datatypes of returned columns has to be compatible.

Comment: If you know, that the two queries will never return rows that intersect (which is your case) you should *always use* `UNION ALL` instead of a UNION that *sorts both data sets and removes duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the double quotes

Oracle SQL allows us to ignore the case of database object names provided we either create them with names all in upper case, or without using double quotes. If we use mixed case or lower case in the script and wrapped the identifiers in double quotes we are condemned to using double quotes and the precise case whenever we refer to the object or its attributes:

Instead use single quotes which essentially works and will give you the result you want

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dce84/4

Comment: `SELECT "FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XXxxxxx" FROM dual;`

This works I know that.

The other thing is the error clearly states the datatype is different
`ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`

One is a string and the column is a number type

Comment: So instead of 

`SELECT 'FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX FROM table1;`



You need to do this probably


`SELECT 20 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT FIELD_NAME_THAT_IS_29_CHAR_XX FROM table1;`

to make it work